# Getting notifications for other peoples questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, notifications

I recently put a bounty on this question [Kinetic theory derivation of viscosity of a gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155795/kinetic-theory-derivation-of-viscosity-of-a-gas) which is not my own. As such, at the moment to check if someone has answered it I am having to physically go onto that question (instead of just looking at my inbox). I think this is a wider issue, lets say there is a question which has been asked and I am interested to know the answer, if this question has currently no answer, I would have to keep going onto that question to see if an answer has been posted. So is there away to get notifications for other peoples question (perhaps even ones that I have no involvement in what so ever).

Comment: I thought Favorite-ing or Bounty-ing post did alert you for new answers.

Comment: @KyleKanos I have certainly never had alert from a favorite-ing (I can't say about bounty-ing since the situation is yet to arise for me),  although I could be wrong.

Comment: This and similar questions are generally more likely to find good answers / have a better impact at the mother meta, [meta.se].

Comment: It is worth pointing out that you now do (or always did) get notifications from such bountied questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are RSS feeds for questions, users, and tags. Look at the bottom right hand corner of the page on the full (not mobile) site for links.